# Billing address as google map link in new order email woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add billing address as google maps link to the New order email in woocommerce which is sent to the admin. This is the requirement of my delivery agents so that it helps them find the delivery address soon.

Please recommend if there is any plugin to implement this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don’t believe there is a plugin for that. But you can do it yourself pretty easily.

Comment: could you plz tell me how can i do it @KrzysiekDróżdż